# Traversing through all possible moves

Tags: java, recursion

Ok I am sort of stuck with this problem.

I have a Puzzle object that has an array for amounts { 1, 2, 3} and an array representing the target {3, 3, 0} and a move function that takes two integers i & j and applies it to the array.

Now I am trying to write a solver for this. So the idea is that we apply all possible values for i & j and keep applying it until we get a desired target.

I am trying to use a recursive method to handle this but what I am not able to grasp is how to stem my recursion into different ways and find the best "set of moves" that gets me to the target.

So the list of possible moves:

(0, 1),
(0, 2),
(1, 0),
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(2, 0)

After each of these move we get a new "amounts array" and we need to apply these moves onto that and check if any of them results in the "target array".

So my pseudocode is:

```
solve(puzzle):
   if puzzle.isSolved: return true;
   else:
        solve(puzzle.move(0, 1));
        solve(puzzle.move(0, 2));
        solve(puzzle.move(1, 0));
        solve(puzzle.move(1, 2));
        solve(puzzle.move(2, 0));
        solve(puzzle.move(2, 1));
```

- We are assuming that puzzle.move function returns the puzzle with new state.

Now I am sure I am doing something horribly wrong here.. but I can't seem to put my finger on it. So any thoughts / hints / pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Ok so couple of things to make this more clear for everyone:

Since puzzle.move returns the puzzle after applying the move, I am thinking of creating a new puzzle so that the recursion goes through that. Basically, what needs to happen is that after each move we will have a new state of amount array.

So after a move (i = 0, j = 1) the puzzle with initial amount of (a, b, c) has an amounts (a-a, b+a, c). We than take this new amount array and apply the next move (i = 0, j = 2) and so one.

But that is just one part of the "tree" there is another path that needs to be checked which is when we apply the move (i = 0, j = 2) on the initial amount and then go on from there.

Hope this helps :)

btw, this is problem is known as Water Jug Problem (http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/Water.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

*I don't actually understand the puzzle you're trying to solve, but I don't think that matters*

There is something horribly wrong - you only stop when you get a positive solution, but you also need to stop it from recursing forever into a non-solution.

Think about what this code will do as a sequence of steps:

```
// Solve puzzle
Is puzzle solved? No.
Move puzzle 0,1
// Solve puzzle
Is puzzle solved? No.
Move puzzle 0,1
// Solve puzzle
Is puzzle solved? No.
Move puzzle 0,1
```

Unless the moves 0,1 .. 0,1 .. 0,1 .. is guaranteed to eventually solve the puzzle, then this algorithm will never end.

You either need to

1. find a way to work out whether a move has "improved" the puzzle,
2. have some cut-off for when a solution is clearly not working.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am going to try to explain a bit more (in my original thread, hope that will help you as well) :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make solve(puzzle.move) to be the recursive function so solve must be responsible for determining what the new arguments to solve will be. The issue is, if you pass puzzle to solve there is no way for solve to infer the values of i and j from the prior call (unless puzzle stores them). I suggest passing in the values of i and j and then call puzzle.move before calling solve recursively.

```
solve(puzzle, i, j):
   if solve(puzzle.move(i, j)): return true;
   else:
      j++;
      if (j == i)
         j++;
      if (j > MAX)
         j = 0
         i++;
      if (i > MAX)
         return false;
      solve(puzzle, i, j);
```

However, I think it is worth noting that any problem that can be solved with recursion can be called without recursion, so let's see what this would like like without it:

```
i = 0;
j = 1;
solved = false;
while (!solved && i <= MAX)
    while (!solved && j <= MAX)
        solved = puzzle.move(i, j);
        j++;
        if (j == i)
            j++;
        if (j > MAX)
            j = 0
            i++;
```

Here, the code is a little simpler and it avoids all the extra calls (which consume limited stack space) - recommended.